# How to data transfer (Import/Export) between two systems?

Tags: command-line, server, minecraft, transfer

I have recently repurposed an old system (Let's say System B) to host a Minecraft server using Ubuntu Server. I am quite new to it, and am I wanting to export data to my desktop (System A), so I can edit files and then import it back to System B. I was wondering what the process is?

System A is running on Windows 10, and System B is running Ubuntu Server 22.04.02 LTS.

Any help is appreciated!